# Textarea a base de datos y recupero problema

Tags: php, base-de-datos, texto

Tengo un problema para mi muy grande jaja
Tengo un formulario que tiene un textarea el cual le agrego un edito (richtext) para poder poner otro tipo de fuente, colores y demás cosas

El problema está al guardarlo en la base de datos me lo guarda así

```
> &lt;div&gt;Soy un texto normal, &lt;i&gt;pero&lt;/i&gt; &lt;font
> color=&quot;#0000ff&quot;&gt;pero no
> &lt;/font&gt;&lt;b&gt;funciona&lt;/b&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
```

Yo lo estoy guardando en la variable de esta forma `$cuerpo = htmlentities($_POST["nota"]);`
La variable $cuerpo es la que guardo en la base de datos

Al querer mostrar los datos, he probado con estas dos formas

```
echo html_entity_decode(addslashes($row['cuerpo']));
echo html_entity_decode($row['cuerpo']);
```

y ambas me lo recuperan pero me hace un desastre con las los div de la web, me saca todo de lugar y no tengo forma de arreglar. Borro el texto desde la base de datos y pongo un texto plano sin nada y se muestra  todo perfecto de vuelta

Que puede ser o en que me estoy equibocando por lo cual esto hace que se arruine todo ?

Espero me puedan ayudar. muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta el contenido original, si es posible en HTML (podrás obtenerlo examinando el código fuente de la página)? Por otra parte, ¿por qué en vez de aplicar estilos directamente no usas una clase y aplicas los estilos a esa clase en `.css`?

Comment: Buenas. Lo hago así porque porque lo que necesito es que uno  copia y pega desde un word ya con un formato de texto y demas y eso se copia en el textarea de mi formulario. 
Por eso no le puedo dar estilo luego.¨
Encontré como cortar  el muestreo a las tantas lineas con css pero me da error en mucas ocacioens y sigue mostrando todo el codigo. No se como solucionarlo realmente